# Multithreaded applications on a single threaded CPU?

Tags: kernel, embedded, multithreading, thread

The motivation behind this question arises from exploring the [Intel Galileo gen2 board](https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/hardware/galileo) which has a single threaded processor.

- I'm looking for a conceptual explanation on what does that mean for all the userspace applications that rely on the existence of threading?
- Does this mean that the kernel needs to be patched so that the system calls for the threading invocation are emulated in software instead of relying on the CPU threading support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-tasking systems handle multiple processes and threads regardless of the number of processors or cores installed in the system, and the number of "threads" they handle. Multi-tasking works using time-slicing: the kernel and every running process or thread each get to spend some time running, and then the system switches to the next runnable thread. The switches happen very frequently, which gives the impression everything is running in parallel even when it's not.

All this happens without any change to the APIs etc. Multi-core systems need to be able to run more threads than they physically support anyway, the single-core case is just an instance of that.

Describing a CPU as single-threaded refers to [simultaneous multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) (SMT, or hyper-threading in the Intel world), not the CPU's ability to run multiple threads (or processes, or tasks). Adding SMT features to a CPU doesn't add any instructions to help running threads, it just allows better use of the hardware in some circumstances.

Comment: I agree, it is the explicit notion of a `single threaded` CPU that got me confused. My current guess it that it doesn't support certain `threading hardware aids` as opposed to single core CPUs that aren't marketed as `single threaded`.

Comment: Ah, I see; "single-threaded" here is in opposition to "hyper-threaded", it doesn't have to do directly with the CPU's ability to run multi-threaded software. (I'll update my answer later.)